# Converting string to formatted date using PHP

Tags: php, string, date

I've the following string:

```
$str = "Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am at Plano B";
```

The `at Plano B` is optional. I would like to convert it to: `TUE 21 FEB 07:30`

Comment: The usual answer is `strtotime()`, but the "at Plano B" is going to confuse it. Is there a common structure to every string (like, "every string will contain "at"")?

Comment: The string can change between this two formats: Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am at Plano B   and   Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am   without the last "at..."

Comment: @Pekka, surely one doesn't need an "at", there's "am" and "pm" to hook any regex off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am at Plano B";
$time = strtotime(trim(substr($str,0,(strrpos("at"))));
echo "Date: " . strtoupper(date('D d M H:i', $time));
```

What do you mean by "at Plano B is optional". Is it sometimes there, sometimes not?

Otherwise:

```
$str = "Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am at Plano B";
preg_match("/[a-z]+, ([a-z]+ [0-9]{1,2}) at ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[am|pm])/i", $str, $match);

$time = strtotime($match[1] + ' ' + $match[2]);
echo "Date: " . strtoupper(date('D d M H:i', $time));
```

Is it always either "Plano B" or empty? or can it also be "Plano A" or something completely diffrent?

See here: http://regexr.com?2vvuj

But you are missing the year in the initial string, so can't parse as strtotime. Also you want output without am/pm.. Do you want to use 24 hour time?

This is not a pretty way, but without the year, i dont think we have much choice..

```
preg_match("/([a-z]+), ([a-z]+) ([0-9]{1,2}) at ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})([am|pm])/i", $str, $match);
$day = substr($match[1], 0, 3);
$mon = substr($match[2], 0, 3);
echo strtoupper($day . " " . $match[3] . " " . $mon . " " . $match[4]);
```

Comment: bugs when the location is missing: `"Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am"`

Comment: it can be 'Plano B', empty or any other string.

Comment: with your example above the output is alway Date: Thu 01 Jan 01:00 with all the date that i've tried :(

Comment: after the `preg_match` add this: `echo "<pre>".print_r($match,1)."</pre>";` to make sure the result is correct. I have not tested the code in PHP, only the regex

Comment: Ehm, I think it's actually missing the year to parse via `strtotime`. Is there a way to add the year to the string? it is not a full date now..

Comment: now i understand the problem was the year missing (: I can append the year to the string in the following way: $str = "Tuesday, 2012 February 21 at 7:30pm at Plano B";
Thanks for your help

Comment: haha ok, basically that was the only answer you needed in the end :-) Dont forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a slightly different solution based on the not as oftenly used [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime). It uses a pre-defined format to parse the string.

**Example:**

```
<?php

// Specify a default timezone just in case one isn't set in php.ini.
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');

$str = "Tuesday, February 21 at 7:30am at Plano B";
if ($time = strptime($str, '%A, %B %e at %l:%M%P')) {
    // This will default to the current year.
    echo strtoupper(date('D d M H:i', mktime($time['tm_hour'], $time['tm_min'], 0, $time['tm_mday'], $time['tm_mon'])));
}
```

**Output:**

```
SUN 01 SEP 07:30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Strip the last at, if its not a time
if(!preg_match("/at [0-9]+:[0-9]+[ap]m$/", $str)) {
  $str = preg_replace("/at [^0-9].*/","",$str);
}

// Then convert to time
$time = strtotime($str);

// Then output in specified format
echo strtoupper(date("D d M h:i", $time));
```